# DNS takes too long to resolve

Tags: web-hosting, dns, page-speed

I have a site and its load time needs improvement. When I monitor it, the DNS takes too long to resolve.

Pls see the results here: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/GOv42ma85/http://www.escalaproperties.com/

Yes, there are a lot of issues (images not compressed, too many requests but my biggest concern bas hecome dns resolving. It takes 14 seconds to get resolved.

I have looked on internet but didn't find anything ( maybe I am searching for the wrong thing ).
Any thoughts, how to speed it up?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that DNS alone takes 14sec to resolve? I think you're misreading something. On quick scan, I never see it go above 1-2 **ms**. (Note that as currently presented, specific to results for your site, this is probably too localized, but it can be approached from a "how to read the Pingdom stats" angle, I guess.)

Comment: Pls have a look here: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/GOv42ma85/http://www.escalaproperties.com/

Comment: That's the same link as above. I *did* go there. I'm asking you exactly what metric you're looking at. What graph, on what page, for what path/file. (Or post a screenshot circling it or something.) There's a huge amount of information there, and frankly I don't see anything that says what you're saying, but I'm also not going to check every single link for you. The only thing I see around ~14sec involves fetching data from *your server*, not the DNS system.

Comment: Sorry for not pinpointing. Pls have a look at this one: http://i43.tinypic.com/j8z9y8.jpg ( load time is 14s ). It might be lesser for you on loading the same page again ( results might be cached. but if you perform the test again it'll show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

It would appear, according to the metric you're using, that DNS is not the real reason that your site is 'slow'. According to this utility, DNS takes 1 milisecond to resolve. 15.73 seconds are spent waiting on the server queue up and send the HTML. I'm thinking the bottleneck is at the web server, not the DNS.

Comment: Yes, I believe it was caused by your server. I am checking your site and I only need 1-2 second to open your site. :)