# How can I decrease load time (see image)

Tags: web-hosting, dns, load-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DNS takes too long to resolve](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28825/dns-takes-too-long-to-resolve)

[image: PingDom Test results]

This website loads pretty fast, in less than 1 second on localhost. I have made it live on the server and load times are as high as 15 seconds.

The initial GET request is taking too long. How to rectify the problem and what exactly is the problem. I have been trying to find solution, but I believe, I am searching the wrong thing.

Also the I'm using Namecheap DNS management.

Comment: "The initial GET request is taking too long" You should re-check what yellow stands for in that graph.

Comment: Is there a solution to solve this problem, and that yellow stands for "wait"

Answer (score 4):

Install a [caching plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=cache) for Wordpress.

Comment: that would not solve the problem.

Comment: What makes you so sure?

Comment: See the image, the first line, the GET request is taking too long, so I think some DNS problem.

Comment: You are incorrect. Here is the key for colors in the Pingdom graph: http://cl.ly/1P3m2U2C1x3j0w0Y3K3y

Yellow indicates "The web browser is waiting for data from the server", which suggests that your server is generating the page HTML slowly, probably due to database contention. This is common in Wordpress installations, and is usually remedied by caching.

Your DNS performance appears to be fine.

Comment: I get your point. I wanted to know, is it possible, that the website was performing extremely well and suddenly the load time increases dramatically

Answer (score 3):

See the [WordPress Optimization codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization).

Also, use:

- [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
- [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a lot of javascript libraries. Remove or combine them.